# werkzeug.routing.BuildError coming for Flask app

Tags: python, html, flask, post

I got an error when trying to run my Flask app of: BuildError: Could not build url for endpoint 'result' with values ['resultFound']. Did you mean 'menu' instead?

The problem has to do with the calling of POST. I have attached the code for 4 files that relate to this error, but I left out the import packages and other parts of the files. I would greatly appreciate your help. Thanks a lot. If you would like any other code I could add it.

This is my main python function that is running the flask app.

```
@app.route("/search", methods=["POST", "GET"])
def search():
    if request.method == "POST":
        user = request.form["searching"]
        return redirect(url_for('result', resultFound = user))
    else:
        return render_template("search.html")

app.route("/<resultFound>")
def result(resultFound):
    return render_template('result.html', nameartist = artistName(resultFound), numfollowers = artistfollower(resultFound))
```

This is the python file that is getting the information for the results.html with the input value from the search.html.

```
def artists(searchinput):
    searchResults = spotifyObject.search(searchinput,1,0,"artist")
    artist = searchResults['artists']['items'][0]
    return artist

def artistname(inputvalue):
    value = artists(inputvalue)
    artistName = value['name']
    return artistName

def artistfollower(inputvalue):
    value = artists(inputvalue)
    artistfollowers = value['followers']['total']
    return artistfollowers
```

This is the search.html that gets the input value.

```
   <form action="#" method="post">
       <input type="text" id="myText" name="searching" value="input artist">
       <p><input type="submit" value="submit" /></p>
   </form>
```

This is the result.html that is using the input value from search.html and getting data with the help of the python file.

```
  <p>The artist {{ nameartist }} has {{ numfollowers }} followers.</p>
```

Comment: Try and print the `user` you get after calling `request.form['searching']` and see whether you get a value or not. Because if you pass `None` as the `result`'s function parameter, flask won't know where to bind the `result` without a parameter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
BuildError: Could not build url for endpoint 'result' with values ['resultFound'].
```

because you are missing `@` in `result` route decorator (`@app` and not `app`)

```
@app.route("/<resultFound>")
def result(resultFound):
    [..]
```